# Is there a way to change default order of series in Maple?

Tags: math-software, maple

The default order when expanding in the software Maple is 6 (six!!!). This is very awkward and annoying because one rarely need even the second (non-trivial) order. In any case, is there a way to change this default number in preferences somewhere? I know I can write a command and specify the order, but I'm talking about the "right-click" thing.

Answer (score 1):

Maple has an environment variable `Order` which controls this.

So, after,

```
Order := 3:
```

you can use the right-click context-menu action for series, and see the effect.

See its help-page [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Order).

Comment: Hi, that only works when you type "series(f(x),x=x_0)", not with the right click thing.

Comment: Also, when I exit and reenter Maple, Order is reset to 6 again. How can one change that so it is 3 forever and ever?

Comment: Ah, I see now what you mean. It would be better if the popup dialogue that appears when using the right-click menu already was populated with the current value of Order rather than 6. Good idea. For your other question, you can put the command to set Order into your initialization file, so it's done at each startup. See http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/reference/initialization

Comment: OK thanks for the help. I guess I cannot yet accept the answer since it does not really solve the problem, but thanks for the input.